# Bindings for data-* attribute

Tags: bootstrap-modal, custom-data-attribute

I was going through some bootstrap samples and found tha data-* attributes:

```
.data-toggle="tooltip"
.data-placement="top"
```

etc.

I just wonder if there is a list of this data-* possible combinations and where can they be found.

Answer (score 0):

From [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp):

> The data-* attributes is used to store custom data private to the page or application.
>
> The data-* attributes gives us the ability to embed custom data attributes on all HTML elements.

CSS Frameworks like Bootstrap uses them a lot to enable and target their components. You can usually find the list in the documentation of the specific component.

[Bootstrap modal documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#via-data-attributes). See also the [options](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#options) section.